# Returning to a text field block again from the query

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a form that prompt for customer name and pass that value to a query,

```
FORM compname 
            customer.cusname 
            WITH FRAME f1.
            UPDATE compname WITH FRAME f1.
```

This form wil pass the compname value to the following query,

```
FOR EACH customer WHERE  customer.name = compname NO-LOCK :
               if available(company) then 
                do:
                CREATE temptt.
                assign temptt.num     = customer.kco
                       temptt.no  = string(customer.kco)
                       temptt.name  = customer.name
                       temptt.status = false.
                END.
              else 
              message "not matched " view-as alert-box.
              end.
```

What i want to do is, if search does not receive any rows, it should again prompt for customer name. what should i do for this ??

how do i call that form again in the "else block" and also, currently I am giving the complete name in the field, but i want to give part of the name, for eg., customer name is "John Smith Doe" and if i input "Smith" it should retrieve the related rows. How should i alter the "Where" clause for this ?? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Repeating the search**

This can be done in several ways. Here's one example:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE customer NO-UNDO
    FIELD cusname AS CHARACTER
    FIELD num     AS INTEGER.

DEFINE VARIABLE compnum  AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE compname AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE QUERY qSearch FOR customer.

FORM compname compnum WITH FRAME f1. 

/* Create some bogus data */
CREATE customer.
ASSIGN customer.cusname = "john doe"
       customer.num     = 1.
CREATE customer.
ASSIGN customer.cusname = "jane doe"
       customer.num     = 2.   
CREATE customer.
ASSIGN customer.cusname = "name name"
       customer.num     = 3.    

loop:
REPEAT:

    CLEAR FRAME f2 ALL.

    UPDATE compname compnum WITH FRAME f1.

    /* Quit if neither name or number is entered */
    IF compname = "" AND compnum = 0 THEN
        LEAVE loop.

    /* If num is entered - search by it, otherwise by name */
    IF compnum <> 0 THEN DO:
        OPEN QUERY qSearch FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK WHERE customer.num = compnum.
    END.
    ELSE DO:
        OPEN QUERY qSearch FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK WHERE customer.cusname MATCHES "*" + compname + "*".
    END.
    GET NEXT qSearch.

    DO WHILE AVAILABLE customer:

        IF AVAILABLE customer THEN DO:
            DISPLAY customer WITH FRAME f2 10 DOWN.
            DOWN WITH FRAME f2.
        END.
        GET NEXT qSearch.
    END.

    /* If we have results - leave the loop otherwise try again */
    IF QUERY qSearch:NUM-RESULTS = 0 THEN
        LEAVE loop.

END.

MESSAGE "Quitting" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

**Searching for part of the name**

There are a couple of operators for matching strings:

*BEGINS*

Tests a character expression to see if that expression begins with a second character expression.

Syntax:

```
expression1 BEGINS expression2
```

Example:

```
FOR EACH customer WHERE NO-LOCK customer.cusname BEGINS "john":
```

*MATCHES*

Compares a character expression to a pattern and evaluates to a TRUE value if the expression satisfies the pattern criteria.

The *pattern* can contain wildcard characters: a period (.) in a particular position indicates that any single character is acceptable in that position; an asterisk (*) indicates that any group of characters is acceptable, including a null group of characters.

Syntax:

```
expression1 MATCHES expression2
```

Example:

```
FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK WHERE customer.cusname MATCHES "*doe*":
```

MATCHES sounds like what you're after but **be adviced:** MATCHES will not utilize indices in the database so whole tables will be scanned. This can/will effect performance and possibly make your queries take long time.

The WHERE clause above replaced with MATCHES would look something like this:

```
FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK WHERE  customer.cusname MATCHES "*" + compname  + "*":
```

*CONTAINS*

There's also a third operator called CONTAINS that uses something called a WORD index. That will require you or your DBA to create these kind of indices in the database first. Read more about word indices and CONTAINS in the online help or in the PDF found here: [Progress ABL Reference](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/pdfs/dvref/dvref.pdf?_ga=1.229930014.303746140.1385476936) (page 1004).

CONTAINS is probably a better idea than MATCHES but will require you to make changes to your database as well.

Comment: Matches and Begins will look for the End and the beginning part of the value. But i want to retrieve the result "John Smith Doe" so the input may be "John" "Doe" "Smith", but i should get the result "John Smith Doe" . Which operator does this ??

Comment: BEGINS will look for the start and MATCHES will look for any part if you do like this: field MATCHES "*doe*" - see the asterisks in the beginning and end. If you do like this: field MATCHES "john*" it will work like BEGINS (only matching the beginning) - but still without indices. And like this: field MATCHES "*smith" matching only the end. I'm adding an example in the answer above.

Comment: but my condition is where customer.num = cusnum or customer.name matches "*" + cusname + "*" . it is giving correct result if i give cusname but it is making problem with cusnum filed. It is retrieving too many rows instead of one row, oif i enter cusnum.

Comment: Changed the example to reflect that... Now If you enter anything but 0 as number it will search by it - otherwise by name. Enter neither name or number it will quit.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not getting wat you are meaning exactly !